# How Do I Use a Variable in a Select Statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I run the following code I get the error : Incorrect syntax near '@num_to_remove'.

Any idea why this doesn't work?

Thanks in advance,
Matt

```
DECLARE @num_to_remove INT
SET @num_to_remove = 2

-- get em_ids for records to delete
WITH em_ids
 AS (SELECT TOP @num_to_remove em_id
       FROM irs_self_cert_em sc
      WHERE     sc.date_cert_loc IS NULL
            AND sc.date_first_cert_email_sent < '2014-10-03')

SELECT * FROM em_ids
```

Comment: What happens if you change
    AS (SELECT TOP @num_to_remove em_id
to
AS (SELECT TOP (@num_to_remove) em_id

Comment: Why would you accept an answer that can't possibly work (and which is not the right way to solve this particular problem anyway)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (Note: I haven't tested it. You can try similar this)

```
DECLARE @num_to_remove INT
SET @num_to_remove = 2

-- get em_ids for records to delete
EXEC
(
    'WITH em_ids
    AS (SELECT TOP ' + CAST(@num_to_remove AS varchar(10)  + 'em_id
       FROM irs_self_cert_em sc
      WHERE     sc.date_cert_loc IS NULL
            AND sc.date_first_cert_email_sent < ''2014-10-03'')
    '
)
```

Comment: You don't need dynamic SQL for this. And your code won't run as written anyway, for at least two reasons: (1) you can't build the expression like that inside of `EXEC()` and (2) this will end up as `SELECT TOP 2em_id` (note no space between `2` and `em_id`).

Answer (score 3):

In regular tSQL, you can only use variables to represent values, not column names or other objects.   I know the numeric value for a "TOP" clause seems like it should qualify but it doesn't.

To use a variable in this way, you have to do [Dynamic SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Hmm, this works fine for me. `DECLARE @t INT = 5; SELECT TOP (@t) * FROM sys.objects;`

Comment: Hmm, works for me too.  Never knew about that.   Since you didn't offer this as an answer, I'll leave this one here for future users.